# Slick carousel full width with center mode not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to create a full width page slider with one slide to be centered and 2 slides will be partially visible at both sides.

But for some reason there is a big white gap visible. I tried with giving img width 100% but the image resolution is distorting.

Jquery code:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
});
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/hn7xsa4y/

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want to try using :

```
$('.slider').slick({
centerMode:true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    variableWidth: true,
    variableHeight: true
});
```

This should remove the gap, but you might need to add some css to make sure that the slick `<div>` will be large enough to display your whole image. You can also modify the css for the related images.

Comment: Brilliant. Working great. Thanks you saved my few hours. One thing is not working properly which is responsiveness. Let me try first.

Comment: I didn't get time to sit with it...will do it later tonight. But I think I need to change the mode from center to something else.

Comment: With CSS3 there are a lot of nice stuff you can do. But I am not that good myself using css. I believe you can try to check out the property you can give to it, like to differenciate computer screen from smart phones' one. Because basically here your are giving a size directly inside the code using px. Try to see with othe way to modify it.

Comment: Greate solution. It's unfortunate that `variableHeight` is not documented.